# Обновление с заменой

Tags: php, mysql

В чем здесь ошибка?
   `$update= $conn->query("UPDATE 'accounts' SET password=REPLACE(password,'%$2y$10$%','%$2a$10$%') where password like '%$2y$10$%'");`

Необходимо выполнить замену в таблице аккаунтов, в поле паролей. Пароли зашифрованы 
BCrypt'om. То есть нужно изменить идентификатор $2y$ => $2a$.

Answer (score 0):

```
$update= $conn->query("UPDATE accounts SET password=REPLACE(password,'%$2y$10$%','%$2a$10$%') where password like '%$2y$10$%'");
```

Ну вроде просто кавычки надо убрать

Comment: Какие именно кавычки и где?

Comment: там где accounts, они не правильные, должны быть такие `` или вообще без

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Что с одинарными, что с двойными.

Comment: Вы блин понимаете что у вас перестанет все работать?

Comment: Вначале решу этот вопрос. Дальше модифицирую запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Решено

```
$sqlupdate= $conn->query ("UPDATE accounts SET password=REPLACE(password,'$2y$10$','$2a$10$')");
```

Обновление происходит корректно.